# Pandas DataFrame to 'traditional' file loading

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a python script that initially loads a csv file:

```
data= []
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
        data.append(re.split(r',',line.rstrip()))
```

But now I am dynamically generating the contents of this csv within python in what results to be a pandas `DataFrame`. My question is what is the most efficient way to get the data to the desired format (list of lists).

An obvious way would be to save the dataframe to a csv and then load it back as above, and another one to convert directly somehow. Is the approach below the way to go?

```
data = df.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, if you have a pandas dataframe `df`, you can use `df.values.tolist()` to get a list of lists of the values.

Here's an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd  
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]) 
>>> df.values 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>> df.values.tolist() 
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>>
```